# Access Query Grouping/Sum

Tags: mysql, vba, ms-access

Im trying to create a Report/Query which groups per age group. My Current Query:

```
SELECT QUE_REP_GENERE_AGEGR.genere, QUE_REP_GENERE_AGEGR.age, Count(*) AS [count] FROM QUE_REP_GENERE_AGEGR
GROUP BY QUE_REP_GENERE_AGEGR.genere, QUE_REP_GENERE_AGEGR.age;
```

Outputs following: (I know Genre is spellt wrong)

[image: Screenshot of Output]

Now would like to sum up to Age groups like 0-9;10-19;20-29;... 
(Yes Im aware that there are currently ony records for one age group)

I have tried to use the grouping function for reports but wasn't succesfull as it doesnt sum up the genres but displays like

```
...
Drama  1
Horror 2
Horror 5
Musical 1
...
```

How can i group that? do i need another Query or can i group in the current one? Is VBA an option?

Comment: You need to define the *age groups*, and determine what *age group* each record belongs to, and then group by *age group* instead of *age*. This is purely about the shape of your data, I don't think VBA can help you here.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done MS-Access in ages, but as I commented, you need to have a concept of "age group" *somewhere*, and group by that.

I'd strongly recommend you define these groups in a table, otherwise your query will have to define them. I think something like this would work (maybe not *exactly* that, but you get the idea):

```sql
SELECT
     genere [Genre]
    ,AgeGroup
    ,COUNT(*) [Count]
FROM (
    SELECT
         genere
        ,CASE WHEN age < 10 THEN '0-9'
              WHEN age < 20 THEN '10-19'
              WHEN age < 30 THEN '20-29'
         END AgeGroup
     FROM QUE_REP_GENERE_AGEGR
    )
GROUP BY genere, AgeGroup
```

Comment: GROUP BY genere  , age / 10

Comment: @BerndBuffen whether you can do that or not, entirely depends on how the groups are defined. And requirements change - one day you'll need a group that goes `14-18` and then the amount of work that change entails depends on how you structured things from the start.

Comment: Bernd Buffens and my solutions are the quick fixes of course, but I like this solution as it allowes me to define age groups more specificly. Thank You

Comment: Just noticed that the SELECT CASE statement can not be used in MS Access! But the similar [switch statement](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Switch-Function-d750c10d-0c8e-444c-9e63-f47504f9e379?CorrelationId=780bb31f-1909-4ffe-9a06-a9737af6c43f&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) can be used